# transfer hundreds of files using ssh from remote http host

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer

I want to download hundreds of files from some website to my own server using ssh, the remote files are in series: 0001.jpg : 0900.jpg

how to do this ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `scp` or `rsync` as just two example methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have HTTP access then I don't understand why you say you want to use SSH...

Here's how to do it over HTTP:

```
curl -f -O http:www.example.com/folder/image[0001-0900].jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

scp accepts wildcards.

ie:

```
scp user@host:/path/* ./path/to/files/locally/
```

Comment: but i don't have access for remote server, only via http

Comment: you said via ssh?  if it's http...

    wget -r -l 1 http://host/path/to/indexoflinks 

may work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scp with your username and password on remote server.